IPP printer page size not available in Windows
I am working for a printer manufacturer and adding IPP support to our small form factor printers which print on 57mm paper roll. The printer works when connected to Linux, but when connected to Windows (10 or 11), the paper size is not showing as an available size (In "Print Preferences" etc) - only "A4" and "Legal" seem to be available.
Any ideas why Windows seems to not allow the small paper size that our printer supports?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

First, see if the driver supports windows custom paper sizes.  You will need to make on that is the width of the paper + the length you want the application to see as a printer page.  See if those pages start showing up after creating them.  See if the driver shows "paper roll" for source.  Only a custom application that knows how to print to rolls would be able to really use it as intended.  Why try to create paper sizes?

In Devices and Printers Control Panel, right-click the printer and select Printing Preferences. Depending on the driver, you might or might not be able to add a custom page size.

Thanks for your comments. Note that this is using IPP (using the "Microsoft IPP class driver"), so there should be no need to install or configure anything on the PC - it should just use whatever paper size(s) are reported by the printer. Also, the Print Preferences dialog does not give any option for "paper roll", custom sizes etc - just "A4" or "Legal".

It seems that Windows supports only a small subset of defined IPP page sizes, does not use custom_ page sizes, and does not allow the user to define custom page size.
It is apparently possible to manually patch .gpd file of the printer, which is a PostScript PPD-like file describing printer capabilities. I tried it and it didn't work for me, but I didn't try hard enough.
The .gpd files are stored in C:\Windows\System32\spool\V4Dirs. The description on the format could be found on MS website: Supporting user-defined paper sizes.
The base principle is described in Custom Page Sizes for Microsoft Print to PDF):

Now, make a backup copy of the GPD file, so you can restore it if you fumble the editing. Then you need to edit the original file and add the following section, immediately after the line *DefaultOption: LETTER :
*Option: CUSTOMSIZE
{
*rcNameID: =USER_DEFINED_SIZE_DISPLAY
*MinSize: PAIR(936000, 1332000)
*MaxSize: PAIR(5346000, 7560000)
*MaxPrintableWidth: 5346000
}

The values for MaxSize are copied from the largest page size already defined (A3) and the values for MinSize are scaled down proportionately from that to represent A8 size. Save the new file somewhere, then copy it over the top of the original file.

I tried to add new page size (North America 6x9) by editing .gpd file and it did nothing, and adding a function to define user-defined page sizes as described above did not help either: there's a new option "User-Defined Size" as a paper size, but no way to set this size (probably requires more modification to .gpd).
Made an issues to CUPS and LPrint project, waiting for experts to reply:

CUPS — How to use proper/custom page size on Android/Windows?
LPrint — How to use proper/custom page size on Android/iOS/Windows?

